# How can i use Instagram widget in magento2 footer section

Tags: magento2

I am trying to Hit following API URL for the Instagram widget.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/XXXXXXX/media/recent?callback=jQuery112402885046003635292_1532581248756&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&count=10;

But I am getting in response

```
{"error_type": "OAuthRateLimitException", "code": 429, "error_message": "You have exceeded the maximum number of requests per hour. You have performed a total of 436 requests in the last hour. Our general maximum limit is set at 200 requests per hour."}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instagram changed this limit to 200 request per hour per user.

Although no official communication. I found this in their documentation.

The Instagram API uses the same rate limiting as the Graph API (200 calls per user per hour) with one exception: the /media/comments edge limits writes to 60 writes per user per hour. Please refer to the Graph API's rate limiting documentation for more information.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview/#rate-limiting

https://techcrunch.com/2018/04/02/instagram-api-limit/

Hope this will be helpful.